# Finding elements in first half of Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I don't understand well this exercise.

```
arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.indexOf(2); // 1
arr.indexOf(4); // -1 since it doesn't exist.

// Write a function to determine if an element
// is in the first half of an array.
// If an element has an odd length, round up
// when counting the first half of an array.
// For example, 1 and 2 are in the first half
// arr.
function inFirstHalf(inputArray, element) {

}
```

I don't got it, what does mean first half of an array?

Comment: I guess it means if *indexOf* returns a value that is less than half of *arr.length*, rounded up if length is odd (which means you'll actually have to round down, since array indexes start at 0).

Comment: @RobG you made my day!

Comment: Thank you @RobG, I am taking this course https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-intro/8/4, I was stuck in that exercise.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the value in a new array created by slicing the original array in two:

```
arr.slice(0, Math.ceil(arr.length/2)) . indexOf(val)
```

Answer (score -1):

You should retrieve the length of the array `arr` using the `length` property. Now you have to check whether the element `index` is smaller than `length` and round up when length is odd.

```
function inFirstHalf(inputArray, element) {
    if ((inputArray.length % 2) === 0) {
        if ((inputArray.indexOf(element) + 1) <= (inputArray.length / 2)) {
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        if ((inputArray.indexOf(element) + 1) <= Math.ceil ((inputArray.length / 2))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you show some examples of how you tested this?

Comment: If the index is less than `inputArray.length / 2`, then by definition it will also be less than the ceiling of that value, so the second check would seem to be unnecessary, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: In this approach the second check is necessary due to the first if statement. The first step is to check whether the array length is odd or not. When the length is not odd the `inputArray.length / 2` check applies. Otherwise (when the array length is odd) the `Math.ceil` check applies. Even if this approach isn't the best (nor a good) one, the task will be solved with the suggested techniques of codeacadamy (and that's what this excercise is for).